# Исключение при SQL запросе к БД

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, исключения, ms-access

Ловлю исключение и не могу понять в чем проблема:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Инструкция INSERT INTO содержит неизвестное имя поля 'ImageIndex'.  Проверьте, что имя задано без ошибок, и повторите операцию."
```

Класс с данным запросом:

```
class MoviesTableMenager
{
    private string ImageIndex { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private string Director { get; set; }
    private string Country { get; set; }
    private int Price { get; set; }
    private string Description { get; set; }
    private OleDbConnection OleDbConnect { get; set; }

    public MoviesTableMenager(string name, string director, string country, int price, string description, string imageIndex)
    {
        Name = name;
        Director = director;
        Country = country;
        Price = price;
        Description = description;
        ImageIndex = imageIndex;
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        string StrConnection = $@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = D:\Serious Projects\AIS_Kinoteatr\CinemaDataBase.mdb;";
        OleDbConnect = new OleDbConnection(StrConnection);
        string cmdText = $"INSERT INTO Films ([ImageIndex], [Name], [Description], [Price], [Director], [Country]) VALUES ('"+ ImageIndex +"', '"+ Name +"', '"+ Description +"', '"+ Price +"', '"+ Director +"', '"+ Country +"')";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, OleDbConnect);

        OleDbConnect.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Здесь исключение
        OleDbConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

[image: Сама таблица в БД]

Comment: Ну нет поля `ImageIndex` в таблице `Films`...

Comment: Ну а поля то в базе на кириллице. =)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Извиняюсь за такой глупый вопрос:) Я почему то думал что оно по положению слева определяет:(